# Visual C++ 2008 (VC9) project in debug fails to execute due to side-by-side error on unavailable VC8 debug crt

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, msvcrt

I am using visual studio 2008 to build an app that has 40 projects. We also link agains some 3rd party libs, which I suspect is causing my headache.  When I build in release it runs fine.  When I try to make a debug build and run in the VS debugger, it won't run because of the familiar sid-by-side assembly error.  I tried copying the contents of Debug_NonRedist from a system that had 2005 installed and can run in debug as a temporary fix, but that didn't work. I would like to find out which library requires the 2005 redist crt, but I don't know how to go about doing that. I tried using depends.exe on the debug executable, but it gives no new information.  How can I find out where the dependency for the vc8 debug runtime is coming from?  Thanks.

Joseph

Comment: Go back to that machine that has 2005 and create a Setup project that uses the merge file Microsoft_VC80_DebugCRT_x86.msm.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317%28v=VS.80%29.aspx  Run the setup.exe it creates on your machine.  Or just don't bother since you can't debug these 3rd party DLLs anyway.

Comment: @Hans, thanks for the link.  I didn't know about Setup projects.  Anyway, for now I installed VC++2005 express and service pack 1 and I am able to run and debug my code.  However, what I really want to do is figure out which 3rd pary lib is causing the dependency and seek an upgrade.

Comment: Look at their manifests.  File + Open + File, select the DLL, RT_MANFEST node.  Or grep the files for "DebugCRT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing VS 2005 express edition and then the service packs it required to run on win7.